Finding Edward Snow & Xiao Qian's translation of "Dog"?
In the paper The Translation and Research of Sichuan Modern and Contemporary Literature in the US it says:

T'ung Tso's translation of Ba Jin's short story "Dog" (1931) in Living China was first published by George Harap in 1936 and republished in the United States in The Voice of China in 1938.

Lu Xun, Cultural Internationalism, Leftist Periodicals and Literary Translation in the 1930s also notes that:

The translator of these three stories, T'ung Tso, was in fact the pseudonym of Snow and his Chinese collaborator Xiao Qian.

Snow here refers to Edward Snow.
Is T'ung Tso's (Edward Snow & Xiao Qian) translation of Ba Jin's short story "Dog" (1931) available anywhere?

One reason it might be hard to find is because 巴金 is Romanized as:

Pa Chin

=====
The story can be found here:
Living China, 1936
In the PDF, it is on p. 92
Which equates to p. 174 in the actual book

Cool‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎
